# groupRowInnerRenderer not being called after a call for api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

It has been a while since i was struggleing with this issue
I made this plunker trying to reproduce the bug i had https://plnkr.co/edit/npifAORP3KAmzrJI
As you can see there is a button "Switch row group" which call a function which itself calls gridApi.setColumnDefs(columnDefs); after changing the grouping row (it sets columnDef.rowGroup = true; for a different column each time) and the groupRowInnerRenderer is being called each time later on.
The bug which i couldn't reproduce is happening in my app since i upgraded the ag-grid vendors to "25.0.1" instead of "23.2.1"

```
"@ag-grid-community/react": "^25.0.1",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "25.0.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^25.0.1",
```

So after i switch the grouping column, the groupRowInnerRenderer is never running again
As it's a frameworkComponents ( a react component), i tried to debug its lifecycle and i found that it gets unmounted after the group row switch and never mounted again.

I then tried to use a vanilla javascript function instead of the react component but the result is similar as it get never called again after the switch

```
import uuidv1 from 'uuid/v1';
export default function groupRowInnerRenderer() {
console.log('groupRowInnerRenderer 22: render RUNNNING ');
return 'youpiii : ' + uuidv1();
}
```

When i downgrade the vendors to version "23.2.1" it all works fine again
Do you have a clue please ?

Answer (score -1):

I finally could solve this issue by debugging in the AG vendor, i found this code throwing a warning in the console
[image]

I then changed the declaration of the groupRowRendererParams accordingly to the new syntax.